# "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" when writing a CSV to a temporary file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to test a function which writes data to a CSV file using a [`tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile). Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
import csv
import tempfile


def write_csv(csvfile):
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['foo', 'bar'])

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})


def test_write_csv():
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as csvfile:
        write_csv(csvfile)
```

This seems in line with how [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) is documented, yet when I run the test (using `pytest`) I get the following error:

```
============================================================ FAILURES ============================================================
_________________________________________________________ test_write_csv _________________________________________________________

    def test_write_csv():
        with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as csvfile:
>           write_csv(csvfile)

csvtest.py:14: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
csvtest.py:8: in write_csv
    writer.writeheader()
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py:144: in writeheader
    self.writerow(header)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <csv.DictWriter object at 0x103bc46a0>, rowdict = {'bar': 'bar', 'foo': 'foo'}

    def writerow(self, rowdict):
>       return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
E       TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any idea what is causing this? It seems to occur when the `rowdict` is `{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar'}`, but I haven't been able to pin it down further.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`tempfile.TemporaryFile()` opens the file in binary mode by default. You need to specify the mode explicitly.

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode = "w") as csvfile:
```

Comment: Also works perfect for tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().